# Export from PowerPoint to animated gif?

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint, gif

Is it possible to export a picture with custom animation from PowerPoint to an animated gif?

Answer (score 10):

Powerpoint 2010 can save directly to windows video format.

Convert to gif from there.

Comment: Can you explain how to convert windows video format to gif

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of services and pieces of software to convert PowerPoint presentations to videos of various types.  [AuthorStream](http://www.authorstream.com/) is a website that converts PPT to MPEG4.  A bunch of programs that do conversion are listed [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/09/how-to-convert-powerpoint-presentation-ppt-to-video-avimpeg-flash-and-cddvd/), some are free and some are not.  There is a [plugin](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/accessories/powerpoint.asp) for [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp) that can convert directly to GIF from PowerPoint.  If you use one of the free products to convert to video, then you can convert that video to images using a tool like [MEncoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder), and those individual images to an animated gif using any of a number of free tools or services, including [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org).

Answer (score 2):

Save your slides as images (JPEG, etc) and then import into Adobe Photoshop. Instructions are here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9F6pxRiL4Hs